# pass core data item between view controllers

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

i am making an app that requires core data to store some information, i have managed to get the app to create the entities and add the information, however i am unable to edit it

i have a list view controller that displays a brief outline of this information and another list view controller which acts as a modal view to allow the user to edit their information.

when the user taps a list item i need the app to show the modal view controller with the selected information loaded from the core data model into the relevant text boxes and when the user clicks save, i need the changes to be saved

at the moment when the user taps the list item the information is not passed into the modal view, NSLog confirms that for me - it tells me the item i tapped in the prepareForSegue: method and is null in the modal view's viewDidLoad:

here's the code:

this is from the MedsList view controller, it displays the information

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
}   //selMed declared at top of file as NSManagedObject *selMed;
    selMed = [self.meds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"SELECTED MED: %@",[selMed valueForKey:@"name"] );
    UIStoryboardSegue *segueString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"editMeds"];

    NSLog(@"%@",segueString);

NSLog(@"%@ %@", @"MED NAME",[self.meds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);

[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"editMeds" sender:indexPath];

}

-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

if ([segue  isEqual: @"editMeds"]) {

NSLog(@"%@ %@", @"SELMED AT PREPARE FOR SEGUE: ",selMed);
UINavigationController *nav = segue.destinationViewController;
MedsEditViewController *dest = (MedsEditViewController *)nav.topViewController;
    dest.med = selMed;
    dest.chName = [selMed valueForKey:@"name"];//chosen med's name
}

    }
}
```

here is MedsEdit.m

```
#import "MedsEditViewController.h"
#import "fibroMappAppDelegate.h"
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@interface MedsEditViewController ()
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context;
}
@end

@implementation MedsEditViewController


@synthesize tbName;
@synthesize tbDose;
@synthesize tbMaxDose;
@synthesize tbType;
@synthesize med;
double dose;
double maxDose;



- (void)viewDidLoad
{ 
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"%@ %@", @"recieved MEDICATION", self.med);
    NSLog(@"%@ %@", @"recieved Name", _chName);
    fibroMappAppDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    context = [delegate managedObjectContext];

    tbName.text = _chName;
}
```

chName is declared in the .h file as a NSString

could somebody please help me work out what i have done wrong? and how to fix it..... i've spent a lot of time on this on and off in the last few months

here is a copy of the log after prepare for segue starts

2013-11-07 14:21:15.475 fibromapp[660:70b] SELECTED MED: med1

2013-11-07 14:21:15.476 fibromapp[660:70b] editMeds

2013-11-07 14:21:15.477 fibromapp[660:70b] MED NAME  (entity: Medication; id: 0x8a6b0a0  ;

data: {

dose = 3;

lastTaken = nil;

maxDose = 5;

name = med1;

type = Miligrams;

})

2013-11-07 14:21:15.479 fibromapp[660:70b] Warning: Attempt to present  on  while a presentation is in progress!

---------------------the following is in the MedsEdit viewDidLoad-------------------------

2013-11-07 14:21:15.497 fibromapp[660:70b] recieved MEDICATION (null)

2013-11-07 14:21:15.498 fibromapp[660:70b] recieved Name (null)

Answer (score 1):

`[segue  isEqual: @"editMeds"]` should be `[segue.identifier  isEqualToString: @"editMeds"]` for a kick off...

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tried to set the MedsEditViewController as your segue.destinationViewController?

Comment: i tried this about a week after i started working on this issue... both in the code and in the storyboard (together and separately) it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

First of all, where in the code you posted are you actually setting the med on the destination controller?  I see

```
dest.med = selMed
```

but it is commented out.  If you never set it, then it won't ever be available.  Could you please reformat and post the complete logs?  It's not clear to me if your code ever reached the SELMED AT PREPARE FOR SEGUE log.

Assuming you did not mean to comment that out, or you received an error I think it may be here - `UINavigationController *nav = segue.destinationViewController` - unless your `MedsEditViewController` is actually a UINavigationController I suspect that the `segue.destinationViewController` is the navigation controller, which in turn is going to present your `MedsEditViewController`.  Double check the documentiation for UINavigationController, but off the top of my head I think you need this:

```
dest.topViewController.med = selMed
```

Comment: i will try your suggestions now, in my first attempts at this i had tried to set med which is an NSManaged object, however when that wasn't working i decided i would just try to pass the name of the chosen med and show it in a text box (i think at one point i also tried fetching the object from the data model from inside viewDidLoad but chName was still null so that didn't work haha)

Comment: i tried too use your suggestions however i have build errors now telling me---'property 'med' not found on object of type 'UIViewController *'

Comment: the log has been updated on the question to show the full log from the moment the user taps an item ---- everything else prior too that simply verifies for me that i am getting to methods in the app's main menu